# PHP : How To Get 'Unmatch' String?

Tags: php

I have this array :

```
$GivenString = array("world", "earth", "extraordinary world");
```

how to get 'unmatch' string of variables like this :

```
$string = 'hello, world'; // output = 'hello, '
$string = 'down to earth'; // output = 'down to '
$string = 'earthquake'; // output = ''
$string = 'perfect world'; // output = 'perfect '
$string = 'I love this extraordinary world'; // output = 'I love this '
```

thanks!

Comment: You can replace every occurrence of a word from the array in each string with the empty string.

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done to solve this problem? Have you reviewed the [string](http://php.net/book.strings) and [array](http://php.net/book.array) function lists for things that might look helpful?

Comment: Is `unmatch('a b c', array('a b', 'b c'))` `'a '` or `' c'`? What about `array('a b', 'a b c')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simple `str_replace` will help you

```
$GivenString = array("world", "earth", "extraordinary");

echo str_replace($GivenString, "", $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

array_diff http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

```
$tokens = explode(' ', $string);
$difference = array_diff($tokens, $GivenString);
```

Comment: Would not work for the last example (i.e. across multiple words).

Comment: What about the 3rd example?    `$string = 'earthquake'; // output = ''` ?

Comment: bro, isn't that array_diff only works for array-to-array comparison? in my case, it's string-to-array.

Comment: Engineer mixed up the order - fixed. @RobertHanson that's what the explode is for

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace` will not help, as there are `$string = 'earthquake'; // output = ''` in example. Here's piece of code that will do your job done.

```
$GivenString = array("world", "earth", "extraordinary world");

foreach ($GivenString as &$string) {
    $string = sprintf('%s%s%s', '[^\s]*', preg_quote($string, '/'), '[^\s]*(\s|)');
}

// case sensitive
$regexp = '/(' . implode('|', $GivenString) . ')/';

// case insensitive
// $regexp = '/(' . implode('|', $GivenString) . ')/i';


$string = 'earthquake';
echo preg_replace($regexp, '', $string);
```